# Change specific tab after authentication - react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I would like to ask if this is possible, basically what what I want to achieve is to change the screen on the same tab after successfully authenticated:

This is my BottomTabNavigator, which has 5 tabs. After login in the `Login Tab` I want to change the screen of the same tab to a Profile Screen. How can I achieve it?

```
const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: SearchNavigator,
    Appointments: AppointmentsNavigator,
    Doctors: DoctorsNavigator,
    Login: LoginNavigator,
    Notifications: NotificationsNavigator
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      activeTintColor: PURPLE_COLOR,
      inactiveTintColor: DARK_GRAY_COLOR
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigation.navigate` prop in your component after a successful login action.

**Example**:

```
class Login extends Component {
  handleLogIn = () => {
    fetch('http://some-login-url', 'POST')
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home'));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleLogIn}>
        <Text>Log In</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

However, using the `TabNavigator` approach isn't straightforward for authentication flow. Consider to use the `SwitchNavigator` in combination with your `TabNavigator` as described in [official docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html).